# Loop over each file in multiple directories and apply MergeSamFiles

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have an many objects called `tst.bam` in three of my subfolders *folder1,folder2,folder3*. I want to merge the bam files present in each  subfolders and name the merged `bam` files with the subfolder name (folder1.bam, folder2.bam, folder3.bam).

command for merging multiple bam files is

```
java -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles \
      I=input_1.bam \
      I=input_2.bam \
      O=merged_files.bam

bam.dir<- c("folder1","folder2","folder3")

for (i in 1:length(folder1)){
      all.bam.files <- list.files(folder1[i], pattern = "pairs.bam",full.names=T)
        szFiles <- list.files(path = folder1[i],pattern = "_pairs.bam$",full.names = TRUE) 
        szNewFiles <- dQuote(szFiles)
NszFiles <- paste(paste("I=", szNewFiles, sep =""),collapse = " ",sep ="")
 system(paste0("java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=5 -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp/ -Xmx8g -jar picard.jar MergeSamFiles"), cat(c(NszFiles,"\n")), "O= ", paste(basename(folder1[i]),".bam", sep = ""))
  }
```

getting error

> Error in system(paste0("java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=5
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp/ -Xmx8g -jar.jar MergeSamFiles"),  :    'intern' must be TRUE or FALSE

I know its not the best way of doing, but eager to look at the elegant way.

Comment: This particular error, `'intern' must be TRUE or FALSE`, is happening because you have a premature `)` inside of `system(paste0(...` causing the `system` function to try to interpret `cat(c(Nsz...` as the `intern` argument. Check `?system` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem inclined to handle bam files using R, you might be interested in `Rsamtools`. It's just as fast as samtools, because it's running samtools compiled C code in the background.
https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rsamtools.html

For example:

```
library(Rsamtools)

bam.dir <- c("folder1","folder2","folder3")

for (dir in bam.dir) {
    bam_files <- list.files(path=dir, pattern="bam$", full.names=TRUE)
    new_file_name <- file.path(dir, "merged.bam")
    mergeBam(files=bam_files, destination=new_file_name)
}
```